# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]' HOW TO CLEAN THIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]'

This is my code

```
 public ActionResult submit (up u, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null){

            string ds = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.Length - 3);
            string p = string.Empty;
            p = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            file.SaveAs(p + file.FileName);

            using (dc)
            {
                u.imag = file.FileName;
                dc.ups.Add(u);
                dc.SaveChanges();
          }

        }
        else {

            return Content("Select File, please");
}

        return RedirectToAction("List");
```

ERROR
    **file.FileName**;

FileUpload Control in MVC4 for images,wordfiles, etc 
This code i put here was from my FileUploadController to put the path where i wan to save the image and fild name in table as imag.

table in database 
up (columns id int, imag varbinary MAX)

Comment: Please include more details on your exception and code. E.g. what is the "up" type of the u variable. is up.imag of type string or byte[].

Comment: You have already saved the file to your server (in the `Images` folder) and there is no point also saving it to the database. Your assigning the name of the file to the database, so your database field needs to be `varchar`, not `varbinary`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you. This is my first week on mvc.